# Add a cell value to the query in Excel using Get Data in Excel 2016

Tags: sql-server, excel

I am using Excel 2016 in which i am using Data => Get & Transform Data => Get Data => From Database ==> From SQL Server Database

I am entering the server and in Advance options (sql statement) i am entering the below code.

I want to use the S2OSS dynamic that should be come from Sheet1 (Cell B1) instead of static in query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    IPADD2288_1R69583LIAA AS MPLANE_IP,
    MRBTS_CTP.CO_DN
FROM
    S2OSS_C_SRT_IPADD_2288,
    S2OSS_CTP_COMMON_OBJECTS MRBTS_CTP
WHERE
    S2OSS_C_SRT_IPADD_2288.OBJ_GID = MRBTS_CTP.CO_GID

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT
    stage_S2OSS_C_LTE_IPNO.IPNO_MPIA_8 AS MPLANE_IP,
    MRBTS_CTP.CO_DN
FROM
    S2OSS_C_LTE_IPNO,
    S2OSS_CTP_COMMON_OBJECTS MRBTS_CTP
WHERE
    S2OSS_C_LTE_IPNO.OBJ_GID = MRBTS_CTP.CO_GID
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Yes but this is already part of LEFT JOIN. I need to see how can i use S2OSS replacement using Excel Cell Value

Comment: "this is already part of LEFT JOIN."....I fail to see what the status of your other joins has to do with the fact that these ones are obsolete